# performance: findAndUpdate VS direct save and remove duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to insert 1000 items each minute in a mongo collection preventi duplicated.

With findAndUpdate/Upsert the server performance decreases a lot.

Saving items without check duplicates the server don't goes slow, but I will need a cronjob to remove all duplicated items.

Which is the best approach to scale this?

- One machine with high RAM? How much?
- Many machines with replica-sets and lower RAM?
- Maybe sharding?

Comment: How do you check to see if they're duplicated? What does the code look like for the `findAndUpdate` call?

Comment: what is findAndUpdate? there is no such operation in mongodb - is that your own code?  possibly there is an inefficiency there.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - I realize now he probably meant `findAndModify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can weed out duplicates automatically by creating an [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/).

Example: When you want to reject documents when there is already a document with the same combination of first_name and last_name, you would create an index like this:

```
db.addresses.ensureIndex( { "first_name": 1, "last_name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

When you already have duplicates in your collection and you want them to get removed when you create the index, you also need to set the dropDups option:

```
db.addresses.ensureIndex( { "first_name": 1, "last_name": 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups:true } )
```

To further increase performance when doing mass-inserts, you can set the write-concern to `w: 0`. This will cause your application to send the documents to the database without waiting for an acknowledgment.

To address your other suggestions: A replica-set does not improve write-performance, because only the primary can accept writes. But you can improve write-performance by setting up a sharded cluster, because writes will be distributed on the cluster-members according to the shard-key.

Comment: Would the operation be faster using the unique index compared to `findAndUpdate`? I've never compared the two. I'd thought they did nearly the same thing (assuming an index existed covering the `find`.

Comment: When you have an appropriate non-unique index, the difference to findAndUpdate might be low. But Without an index, findAndModify will have to scan the whole collection to find duplicates, which can take a while with big collections.

Comment: amazing explanation, thanks. I'll find more about write-concern and sharding. Thanks!

Comment: good answer, but rather than recommending writeConcern w:0 I would recommend batching up inserts with continueOnError:true and w:1.  That way you gain the benefit of sending larger batches and only checking for success after each batch.

Comment: just and advise: for string indexes I had to use: db.users.ensureIndex({first_name:"text"},{unique:true,dropDups:true});

Comment: @Leabdalla I was assuming that your collection is still empty and doesn't contain any duplicates yet. I updated the answer. But I doubt that it has anything to do with the field being a string. Normal MongoDB indexes are typeless, just like everything in MongoDB (there are two special indexes which *are* typed, geo-indexes and full-text indexes, but these are irrelevant in this case).

Comment: This approach will now result in a dup key error when using the latest MongoClient for Node.js